# Make PayPal Application Go Live After Receiving Live App ID

Tags: paypal

I have receive the Live App ID for my PayPal app after I registered it, as well as tested its IPN in sandbox mode.

What would be the next steps to making the app go live?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would swap out the sandbox URL to the live URL and secret/credentials with the new live credentials in your script. That's pretty much it. For most endpoints it is as simple as removing the ".sandbox." from the URL. for example

MERCHANT API SOAP "SANDBOX" ENDPOINT

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
```

MERCHANT API SOAP LIVE ENDPOINT

```
https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/
```

This works for the rest API as well if I remember correctly.

here is the list of classic endpoints

[PayPal Classic Endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/endpoints/)

and REST endpoints

[PayPal REST endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#api-endpoints)

Comment: ^Where would the live URL be available for my app? I have the URL of my IPN, but the sandbox screen from which I test my IPN has this general URL: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

Comment: so depending on what API you are calling you will remove ".sandbox." from the url you call in your script. Hope that helps.